# MapKit - How do I change my custom annotation view's tap "zone"?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I just implemented a custom annotation view and I have a custom callout for it as well. Showing the callout ONLY works when I tap the very top-left corner of my custom annotation view (which is a rectangle). How can I fix it so that I can tap the center of my custom annotation view and it will show the callout ? It is very annoying to have to tap a specific corner of the custom annotation view just to see the callout appear.

I tried to create give my annotation view a centerOffSet value but it did not fix the problem at all... how do I make it so that tapping anywhere on the custom annotation view will bring up the callout view ?

Comment: Have you tried implementing `pointInside:` or `hitTest:` on your annotation view?

Comment: No, what would those help me do ? I'm mainly annoyed because it seems that my annotation views are just not getting placed correctly.

Comment: Ok I just implemented pointInside. When I tap on the annotation view, the annotation view does indeed receive my tap event. I should say, there is a label in the custom annotation view and I am worried that this might be why this isn't working. Earlier, I noticed it had user interaction disabled, so I enabled it, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Implement `pointInside:` and return true when the point is inside the bounds of your annotation view

Comment: Yup, I did that (see comment above).

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your custom annotation view's frame correctly? Try set the frame to say CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100), and self.backgroundColor to  [UIColor grayColor], I think the clickable area will be (100, 100) big shown as gray rectangle.